# Regex not matching string in scheme but works on other platform

Tags: scheme, guile

I am running `string-match` using the pattern `[ \[\]a-zA-Z0-9_:.,/-]+` to match a sample text `Text [a,b]`. Although the pattern works on regex101, when I run it on scheme it returns `#f`. Here is the regex101 [link](https://regex101.com/r/aYEUwX/1).

This is the function I am running

`(string-match "[ \\[\\]a-zA-Z0-9_:.,/-]+" "Text [a,b]")`

Why isn't it working on scheme but works eleswhere? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussing the issue on the guile gnu mailing list, I found out that Guile's `(ice-9 regex)` library uses POSIX extended regular expressions. And this flavor of  regular expression doesn't support escaping in character classes `[..]`, hence that's why it wasn't matching the strings.

However, I used the following function as a workaround and it works:

`(string-match "[][a-zA-Z]+" "Text[ab]")`

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with your regular expression syntax as it is quoted correctly so I assume there must be a bug in Guile, or the regexp library it uses, where `\]` just isn't interpreted the correct way inside brackets. I found a workaround by using the octal code point values instead:

```
(string-match "[A-Za-z\\[\\0135]+" "Text [a,b]")
; ==> #("Text [a,b]" (0 . 4))
```

Your regular expression isn't very good. It matches any combination of those chars so `"]/Te,3.xt[2"` also matches. If you are expecting a string like "Something [something, something]" I would rather have made [/[A-Z][a-z0-9]+ [[a-z0-9]+,[a-z0-9]+]/](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5BA-Z%5D%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%20%5C%5B%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%2C%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%5C%5D) instead. eg.

```
(define pattern "[A-Z][a-z0-9]+ \\[[a-z0-9]+,[a-z0-9]+\\]") 
(string-match pattern "Test [q,w]")     ; ==> #("Test [q,w]" (0 . 10))
(string-match pattern "Be100 [sub,45]") ; ==> #("Be100 [sub,45]" (0 . 14))
```

Comment: running `(match:substring (string-match "[ A-Za-z\\[\\0135]+" "Text [a,b]"))` returns `Text [a,b` and still doesn't match the `]`.  Also since, I am trying to match long chemical names the order of the characters doesn't matter